# How to retain the data of dynamically added table rows after invalid form input in jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

`I have here a laravel project with a dynamic table in a modal. The dynamic table is working fine. However, after submitting the form with an invalid input, the dynamically added table rows resets and I'm unable to retain the values added by the user.

Here's the code of the modal that contains the dynamic table:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addOrderModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Deliver Items</h3>
                <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" id="forms">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="location" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Location</label>
                                <select name="location" id="location" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Location</option>
                                    <option value="ORTIGAS">ORTIGAS</option>
                                    <option value="A-JUAN">A-JUAN</option>
                                    <option value="MARIKINA">MARIKINA</option>
                                </select>
                                @error('location')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="checkoutdate">Checkout date</label>
                                <input type="date" required name="checkoutdate" id="checkoutdate"
                                    class="form-control" value="{{ old('checkoutdate', '') }}" />
                                @error('checkoutdate')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="client">Client</label>
                                <input type="text" required name="client" id="client" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('client', '') }}" placeholder="Enter client name" />
                                @error('client')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="contact">Contact Person</label>
                                <input type="text" required name="contact" id="contact" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('contact', '') }}" placeholder="Enter contact person" />
                                @error('contact')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="site">Site/Event</label>
                                <input type="text" required name="site" id="site" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('site', '') }}" placeholder="Enter site/event" />
                                @error('site')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="address">Address</label>
                                <input type="text" required name="address" id="address" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('address', '') }}" placeholder="Enter address" />
                                @error('address')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="srnumber">SR No.</label>
                                <input type="text" required name="srnumber" id="srnumber" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('srnumber', '') }}" placeholder="Enter SR no." />
                                @error('srnumber')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="ponumber">PO No.</label>
                                <input type="text" required name="ponumber" id="ponumber" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('ponumber', '') }}" placeholder="Enter PO no." />
                                @error('ponumber')
                                    <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicTable">
                                <thead class="table-dark">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SKU</th>
                                        <th>Product Code</th>
                                        <th>Model</th>
                                        <th style="width:13%">Quantity</th>
                                        <th>UOM</th>
                                        <th>Item Description</th>
                                        <th>Serial No.</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr>


                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="addmore[0][sku]" placeholder="SKU"
                                            class="form-control" />
                                    </td>

                                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][productcode]"
                                            placeholder="Product Code" class="form-control" /></td>

                                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][model]" placeholder="Model"
                                            class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" name="addmore[0][quantity]" placeholder="Quantity"
                                            class="form-control" /></td>

                                    <td><select name="addmore[0][uom]" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="UNIT/S">UNIT/S</option>
                                            <option value="PANEL/S">PANEL/S</option>
                                            <option value="PC/S">PC/S</option>
                                        </select></td>

                                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][itemdescription]"
                                            placeholder="Item Description" class="form-control" /></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <textarea name="addmore[0][serialnumber]" class="form-control" cols="15" rows="1"
                                            placeholder="Serial no."></textarea>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="border border-white"><button type="button" name="add"
                                            id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                                            style="background-color: #4D83FF; color: white;  border-color: #4D83FF;"><i
                                                class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></button></td>

                                </tr>
                                @if ($errors->any())
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        Please fill out all of the table fields.
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="submitButt" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Here is the script of the dynamic table:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0;
        $("#add").click(function() {
            ++i;

            $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addmore[' + i +
                '][sku]" placeholder="SKU" class="form-control"/></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore[' +
                i +
                '][productcode]" placeholder="Product Code" class="form-control"/></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore[' +
                i +
                '][model]" placeholder="Model" class="form-control"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addmore[' +
                i +
                '][quantity]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control"/></td><td><select name="addmore[' +
                i +
                '][uom]" class="form-control"><option value="Units">Unit/s</option><option value="Panels">Panel/s</option><option value="Pcs">Pc/s</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore[' +
                i +
                '][itemdescription]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control"/></td><td><textarea name="addmore[' +
                i +
                '][serialnumber]" placeholder="Serial No." class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></td><td class="border border-white"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-tr" title="Remove item"><i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i></button></td></tr>'
            );
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        });
    </script>
```

I tried using this script but it is not working:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#forms').on('submit', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default form submission

            // get the form data
            var formData = $(this).serialize();

            // send an AJAX request to the server to validate the form data
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{route("orders.store")}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'success') {
                        // if the form data is valid, submit the form
                        $('#forms').off('submit').submit();
                    } else {
                        // if the form data is invalid, show the error messages
                        $.each(response.errors, function(key, value) {
                            $('#'+key).addClass('is-invalid');
                            $('#'+key+'-error').html(value); // add the error message to the error element
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) { // handle errors with the AJAX request
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
                    alert(errorMessage);
                    //$('#form-error').html(errorMessage); // add the error message to a general error element
                }
            });
        });

        // remove the error message when the user changes the input
        $('input, select').on('change', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('is-invalid');
            $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-error').html('');
            $('#form-error').html('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

`